# How to change a dropdownlist menu to a table menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As what I've done, the menu was **as the dropdownlist** whenever mouseover. However, I would like to **change** it **to a table menu** as the image below. (I am not good at drawing so the image which I just make, is a sketch to let you amaze what I'm looking for).

[image]

Each row in the table will have **4 columns** so that it would **fix** to `48 weeks` as an example:

> Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4
>
> Week 5 | Week 6 | Week 7 | Week 8
>
> ...
>
> Week 45 | Week 46 | Week 47 | Week 48

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NwV8f/)**

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="out_per_chart">
<li>
    <div class="yearly">
        <a class="_link_year" href="/SiteAssets/OutputPerformanceChartForYear.aspx?week=48&amp;month=12&amp;year=2014">2014</a>
        <div class="container1">
            <ul class="sub-menu1">
                <li>
                    <div class="monthly">
                        <div class="title">Monthly</div>
                        <div class="container2">
                            <ul class="sub-menu2"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="weekly">
                        <div class="title">Weekly</div>
                        <div class="container3">
                            <ul class="sub-menu3"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#out_per_chart .title {
    border: 2px solid #2676ac;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 40px;
    color: #2676ac !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

    #out_per_chart .title:hover {
        border: 2px solid #259add;
        cursor: default !important;
        background: #259add;
        color: #FFF !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }

.container1 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: -10px;
    padding-top: -5px;
}

.container2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.container3 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

._link {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #2676ac;
    padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
    width: 30px;
    color: #2676ac !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    ._link:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #259add;
        background: #259add;
        color: #FFF !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

._link_year {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #2676ac;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    color: #2676ac !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    ._link_year:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #259add;
        background: #259add;
        color: #FFF !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

#out_per_chart li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    #out_per_chart li.week_num, #out_per_chart li.month_num {
        margin-left: 60px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

#out_per_chart .weekly {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ms-WPHeader").find(".ms-WPHeaderTd").closest("table").hide();
    $(".monthly").hover(function () {
        var num_week;
        var num_month = 12;
        var current_year = 2014;
        for (i = num_month; i >= 1; i--) {
            $(".sub-menu2").after("<li class='month_num'><a class='_link' href='/SiteAssets/OutputPerformanceChartForMonth.aspx?week=" + i + "&month=" + i + "&year=" + current_year + "'>Month " + i + "</a></li>");
        }
    },

    function () {
        $(".month_num").hide();
    });

    $(".weekly").hover(function () {
        var num_week = 48;
        var num_month;
        var current_year = 2014;
        for (i = num_week; i >= 1; i--) {
            $(".sub-menu3").after("<li class='week_num'><a class='_link' href='/SiteAssets/OutputPerformanceChartForWeek.aspx?week=" + i + "&month=" + (parseInt(i / 4.01) + 1) + "&year=" + current_year + "'>Week " + i + "</a></li>");
        }
    },

    function () {
        $(".week_num").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just some things to note. 1) Your code currently creates new elements every time you hover over it. Hover over the menu a few times and inspect it with a DOM inspector and you'll see hundreds of nodes. 2) `<li>` elements are being added AFTER the `<ul>` instead of inside it 3) The link for months seems to be incorrectly incrementing the week numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwV8f/2/)**.

I have updated the CSS,HTML and JS. Its tough to post all the changes here.

### Main highlights:

**HTML :**

```
<table class="sub-menu2"></table>
<table class="sub-menu3"></table>
```

---

**JS:**

```
$(".monthly").hover(function () {
        var num_week;
        var num_month = 12;
        var current_year = 2014;
         $(".sub-menu2").after("<tr class='month_num'>");
        for (i = num_month; i >= 1; i--) {
            $(".container2").show();
             if(i%4 == 0){
                $(".sub-menu2").after("</tr><tr class='month_num'>");
            }                
            $(".sub-menu2").after("<td><a class='_link' href='/SiteAssets/OutputPerformanceChartForMonth.aspx?week=" + i + "&month=" + i + "&year=" + current_year + "'>Month " + i + "</a></td>");
        }
    },

    function () {
        $(".container2").hide();
});
```

Similarly for Weekly.

To avoid repetition of the elements(to check if menu is existing),

```
if(!($(".container2").has('tr').length)){}
```

---

**CSS :**

```
#out_per_chart tr {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li .yearly:hover .container1{
    display:block !important;
    top:26px;
    left:5px;
}
.container1 {
   display: none !important;
   position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/NwV8f/3/

Comment: Code only answers, while they may be correct, are rarely as informative as ones that also explain why. Consider adding some comments or an explanation to you post.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. But comment's **shaunakde** is quite satisfied my problem.